# cakephp3 Class DateTime not found

Tags: cakephp, plugins, cakephp-3.0

I'm trying to convert my cakephp plugin from 2.X to 3.

I have a little problem inside my component plugin at this line:

```
$dStart = new DateTime($now); //$now = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

return me this error:

```
Error: Class 'CurrencyConverter\Controller\Component\DateTime' not found
```

Seems that it search DateTime inside my plugin directory.
How can I solve it?

Thanks

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Try:

```
$dStart = new \DateTime($now);
```

because CakePHP 3.0 using namespaces and if you not add a root namespace it will be looking for class under current namespace.