# Cakephp 3 find() within 2 hours

Tags: php, datetime, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

This is pretty straight forward but I can't find it in the manual. I did this in cake 2 but can't find how to use the new ORM. I am doing a basic user changed password token. I want to check if the user was modified within the last 2 hours

```
 $query = $this->Users->find('all', [
        'conditions' => ['token' => $token],
        'limit' => 1,
        'where'=> ['modified' =>  /*new Datetime(-2 hours )*/  ]
    ]);
```

thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There seem to be several issues with the snippet you provide. The `-2 hours` argument of `DateTime` isn't inside quotes and `modified` doesn't have a comparison operator. Furthermore, you're using an array of options for `find()` which means all `WHERE` arguments should be inside `conditions` key not in a separate `where` key.

This should work:

```
$query = $this->Users->find('all', [
    'conditions' => [
        'token' => $token,
        'modified >' =>  new \DateTime('-2 hours'),
    ],
    'limit' => 1,
]);
```

Comment: I got this error before Error: Class 'App\Controller\Datetime' not found 
but i thought Date time was part of php, i have to attach some kind of 'use' on top"

Comment: @artSir **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29500225/cakephp3-class-datetime-not-found** You may want to read on how [**namespaces in PHP**](http://php.net/namespaces) work.

Comment: And shouldn't this be `>` (greater than)?

Comment: About the comparison being opposite to what the user asked, you're right @ndm, I misread the question. I'm fixing it now, as well adding the global scoped DateTime.